# Can I call a dialog, while other dialog is opened?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro, which is called on event SelectionChange. This macro have to check, what template is attached to the document. It is possible, that attached template doesn't exist on computer that is opening the document. I need to know, when this occurs, so I can't use ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate (it would show simply Normal.dot, when template doesn't exist). So, I use:

```
Application.Dialogs(wdDialogToolsTemplates).Template
```

And that works fine.
But, when I try to find something in document by ctrl+F, selection is changed while searching and event fires. Macro is called, but on the line above I get an error:

> This method or property is not available because the find and replace dialog box is active

So, the question is - is there a way to use this property, while the find and replace dialog box is active...? Or mabe - is there a way to check, if find and replace dialog box is active?

Comment: what do you think of adding `On Error Resume Next` to your code?

Comment: Well, I could do that ;) And I will, if I won't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

As I suggested in comment you could try to use `On Error Resume Next` to get rid of the error you have. However, I made some tests and that could be interesting for you what I have found out. You could add error handling in two ways which will have different outcomes.

```
'1st attempt will keep Find-Replace window and it will omit error
On Error Resume Next
Debug.Print Application.Dialogs(wdDialogToolsTemplates).Template
On Error Goto 0


'2nd attempt will close Find-Replace window and will return template name
 On Error Resume Next        'this seems to be unnecessary anyway
 Dim tmpDialog As Dialog
 Set tmpDialog = Application.Dialogs(wdDialogEditFind)
 'Find-Replace window will be closed at this stage
 Debug.Print Application.Dialogs(wdDialogToolsTemplates).Template
```

Tried and tested for Office-Word-2010.